# White-box webpage testers

Tags: tools, web, whitebox

I wrote a webPage and i want to localy scan all files in search of somes common vulnerabilities.

I searched on the internet a lot and i can't find white-box tools as I thought.
Instead of this, there are many black-box tools.

Maybe do you know some, free or maybe commercial tools for thats type of tests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather offtopic because product recommendations are not allowed in this site.

At the [OWASP site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Static_Code_Analysis) you have some of applications of your interest.